# How to mock if return value is an abstract class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, virtual, googletest, googlemock

How can I mock/write the EXPECT_CALL if the method I am trying to mock returns an abstract class?

Here is my mock. I implemented it this way (workaround) since GetMouse is non-virtual. I do not really want to make it virtual for the sake of being able to mock it.

```
class DeviceMock: public Device
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(GetMouseWrapper, IMouse*(void));

    virtual IMouse* GetMouse(void)
    {
        return GetMouseWrapper();
    }
};
```

And in my test it looks like this:

```
auto deviceMock = std::make_unique<DeviceMock>();
auto mouse = std::make_unique<IMouse>();

EXPECT_CALL(*deviceMock , GetMouseWrapper()).WillOnce(Return(mouse.get()));
EXPECT_EQ(S_OK, sut_->Init());
```

So of course I cannot instantiate IMouse. But how can I write an EXPECT_CALL for this? Thoughts??

Comment: return `nullptr` or create derived class from `IMouse` (`MouseMock` for example)?

Comment: This works perfect! Why the eff didn't I think of that!? Thanks much @Jarod42!